# Laravel - Select data to Display in Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to ask if ever I can limit my data in table. I want to remove one data out of my 6 data.

here is my table

Now I want to remove number 3 row which is **SESSION_VALIDITY** how can I remove that data and make it just 5 data in my table? I want to limit my data coz' I dont need to view SESSION_VALIDITY. help thanks

my ***Index***

```
 @foreach ($settings as $setting)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $setting->settings_code }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $setting->subject}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $setting->description }}</td>

                    <td><a href="/admin/settings/{{ $setting->id }}/edit" class="fa fa-edit btn btn-info"></a></td>
                </tr>      
                @endforeach
```

my ***Controller***

```
 public function index()
{
    $settings = Setting::all();
    return view('admin.settings.index', compact('settings'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to not show that row in your $settings data, you can exclude it using your query like this.

```
public function index()
{
    $settings = Setting::where('settings_code', '<>', 'SESSION_VALIDITY')->get();
    return view('admin.settings.index', compact('settings'));
}
```

If you want to delete it entirely, you can run a one-time function to delete that row from the table.

```
public function deleteSessionValidity()
{
    $setting = Setting::where('settings_code', 'SESSION_VALIDITY')->first();
    $setting->delete();
}
```

Comment: out of many answers i hink this this is more valuable. on your first answer can i unshow more than 1 data?

Comment: Yes you can - you can chain more instances of the where function with the same syntax.  `$settings = Setting::where('settings_code', '<>', 'SESSION_VALIDITY')->where('settings_code', '<>', 'EXAMPLE')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your query in the controller.

Instead of `Setting::all()`, you should use:

```
$settings = Setting::where('settings_code', '!=', 'SESSION_VALIDITY')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function index()
{
    $settings = Setting::where('settings_code', '!=', 'SESSION_VALIDITY')->get();
    return view('admin.settings.index', compact('settings'));
}
```

**OR**

```
 @foreach ($settings as $setting)
                <tr>
                 @if($setting->settings_code != "SESSION_VALIDITY")
                    <td>{{ $setting->settings_code }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $setting->subject}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $setting->description }}</td>

                    <td><a href="/admin/settings/{{ $setting->id }}/edit" class="fa fa-edit btn btn-info"></a></td>
                 @endif
                </tr>      
                @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

inside `foreach` put `if` statement

like:

```
@foreach ($settings as $setting)
    @if ($setting->settings_code != "SESSION_VALIDITY")

     your <td> here

    @endif
@endforeach
```